# Read a CSV file with multiple values per label

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with the following structure:

```
# Parameters :,            P1,   P2,   P3
2012-01-01 01:01:55.000000,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,8,9
2012-01-01 01:01:56.000000,4,9,2,0,2,1,1,6,8
...
```

How to read it using **Python** (and optionally Pandas) to have the following result:

```
{'2012-01-01 01:01:55.000000': {'P1': [1, 2, 3], 'P2': [4, 5, 6], 'P3': [7, 8, 9]},
 '2012-01-01 01:01:56.000000': {'P1': [4, 9, 2], 'P2': [0, 2, 1], 'P3': [1, 6, 8]}}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you add more rows and explain what your output should look like? One line isn't very descriptive.

Comment: What indicates the difference between 1,2,3 and 4,5,6? Is there logic to how they are assigned to P1 or P2?

Comment: @coldspeed: Done

Comment: standard q: what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

With `csv.reader` object and `itertools.islice()` function:

```
import csv, itertools

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)[1:]   # getting `P<number>` keys
    d = {}
    for l in reader:
        d[l[0]] = {header[i]: list(itertools.islice(l[1:], i*3, i*3+3)) for i in range(len(header))}

print(d)
```

The output (for 3 input lines):

```
{'2012-01-01 01:01:55.000000': {'P2': ['4', '5', '6'], 'P1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'P3': ['6', '8', '9']}, '2012-01-01 01:01:56.000000': {'P2': ['0', '2', '1'], 'P1': ['4', '9', '2'], 'P3': ['1', '6', '8']}}
```

Note, that ***dict*** in Python is unordered structure.
To obtain an ordered structure define the resulting dict as `OrderedDict` object (from `collections` module)

```
...
d = collections.OrderedDict()
```

In that case the result would be:

```
OrderedDict([('2012-01-01 01:01:55.000000', {'P1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'P2': ['4', '5', '6'], 'P3': ['6', '8', '9']}), ('2012-01-01 01:01:56.000000', {'P1': ['4', '9', '2'], 'P2': ['0', '2', '1'], 'P3': ['1', '6', '8']})])
```

Answer (score 0):

**With pandas and numpy**

```
with open('tst.csv') as f:
    _, *params = map(str.strip, f.readline().split(','))

d1 = pd.read_csv(
    'tst.csv', comment='#', header=None,
    index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

i = d1.index.rename(None)
v = d1.values
t = v.reshape(v.shape[0], -1, v.shape[1] // len(params)).transpose(1, 0, 2)

pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(params, t.tolist())), i)

                            P1         P2         P3
2012-01-01 01:01:55  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [6, 8, 9]
2012-01-01 01:01:56  [4, 9, 2]  [0, 2, 1]  [1, 6, 8]
```

---

**Without**

```
with open('tst.csv') as f:
    _, *params = map(str.strip, f.readline().split(','))
    k = len(params)
    d = {ts: dict(zip(
        params,
        (data[i*len(data)//k:(i+1)*len(data)//k] for i in range(k))
    )) for ts, *data in map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','), f.readlines())}

d

{'2012-01-01 01:01:55.000000': {'P1': ['1', '2', '3'],
                                'P2': ['4', '5', '6'],
                                'P3': ['6', '8', '9']},
 '2012-01-01 01:01:56.000000': {'P1': ['4', '9', '2'],
                                'P2': ['0', '2', '1'],
                                'P3': ['1', '6', '8']}}
```